# Title tag on home using front-page template not showing

Tags: title, wp-title

Currently in header I have the following:

```
<title>
    <?php wp_title(' | ', true, 'right'); ?>
    <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
</title>
```

I tried adding if statement like the following below that did not work it displayed as the following: Roots Restaurant    Roots Restaurant

```
<?php if(is_front_page()) {bloginfo('name');}?>
```

It should display as Home | Roots Restaurant

on Home page the title tag looks like the following - Roots Restaurant. So it is missing Home |

Comment: It's clearer to put in your question one piece of code which shows how your entire code looks now.

Comment: @mozboz updated the description

Comment: Did you add theme support for the title-tag (in functions.php)?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the bug, pasting the solution here.

```
        <?php
            if (is_front_page()) {
                echo 'Home | ';
                bloginfo('name');
            }
            else {
                wp_title(' | ', true, 'right');
                bloginfo('name');
            }
        ?>
```